# Converting IDC_Edit text to hexadecimal WORD

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an IDC_Edit text box set which will accept hexadecimal space-separated values that I'm wanting to convert into a WORD. I'm wanting the control to mimic the array, but I'm really unsure how to complete the conversion.

Basically, if I input:

```
"12 AB"
```

I need the resulting WORD to equal:

```
0x12AB
```

As someone who rarely dabbles with C++, let alone the WinAPI, I'm really stumped as to how to do this. My current code is:

```
HWND hTextInput = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_EDIT);
DWORD dwInputLength = Edit_GetTextLength(hTextInput);

char* resultString = new char[dwInputLength+1];
memset(hTextInput , 0, dwInputLength+1);

WORD result = (resultString[0] << 8) | resultString[1];
```

This pulls the `IDC_EDIT` control's text and length and turns it into a `char*` array. This then attempts to convert into a WORD, but obviously this only currently takes the first two characters (`12`) in this case.

How can I make this pull `"12 AB"` into the `char*` array as `[0x12, 0xAB]` (rather than `["1", "2", "A", "B"]`) so that I can then shift the two bytes into a WORD?

Comment: Check out [`strtol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4z2wdyc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WORD Readhex(const char *p)
{
  char c ;
  WORD result = 0 ;

  while (c = *p++)
  {
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
      c -= '0' ;
    else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
      c -= 'A' - 10 ;
    else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
      c -= 'a' - 10 ;
    else
      continue ;

    result = (result << 4) + c ;
  }

  return result ;
}

...
HWND hTextInput = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_EDIT);
DWORD dwInputLength = Edit_GetTextLength(hTextInput);

char* resultString = new char[dwInputLength+1];
GetWindowText(hTextInput, resultString, dwInputLength+1) ;

WORD result = ReadHex(resultString) ;
```

You also forgot the GetWindowText; and filling the buffer with zeros (memset) is not necessary.
The strtol function as suggested will not work for you because strtol will consider the space as a terminator. Maybe you should also consider to do some error checking, for example if the user enters garbage. The ReadHex function above simply ignores any non hex digits.